# Write permission error with Heroku + Activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am running into a permissions error only when I try to run my app on heroku. My app works perfectly on my local machine but when I push it to heroku, I get a write error in the logs:

```
2011-10-27T16:55:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /app/public/stylesheets/active_admin.css):
```

I am not quite sure how to fix this since it works on my local machine. Why would this file need public write permissions?

EDIT: Why would activeadmin need write access to that file? How do I work around that?

Answer (score 3):

Heroku has a read only file system. See http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

If you make a new app on cedar, you'd be able to write, but it won't stick around. See http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-isolation#ephemeral_filesystem

If you continue to have problems, you should contact support http://suport.heroku.com

Comment: I did contact them. They told me to chmod my local file to read only and get it to work. Any idea why that file would need to have write access?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveAdmin uses Sass and tries to compile it live, but Heroku disallows this.

To fix, I have this at the top of `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` (outside of the `ActiveAdmin.setup` block):

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:never_update] = true
```

Source: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/44#issuecomment-1305038

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround would simply be to save the active_admin.css file (when you're on your local machine) and simply upload it to your css folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I found this initializer to fix the path for the CSS file.

https://gist.github.com/1012619

It's work perfect for me.